# Is there a way to send GET request(s) over wifi to an ip-address instead of HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, networking, kotlin

So basically I'm creating an android application and I want to communicate with a device that's on the same local network. The point is to request XML files and recieve them on my phone. Is there a way to do this using IP-addresses? Previously I've only done it using HttpUrlConnection (like the example below) I would love if someone brighter could enlighten me in this subject, thanks.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.connect();
            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
```

Comment: @AmrBerag Maybe I wasn't clear enough, previously I used it with an URL and not IP-address. In my previous project i did a request to "http://data.goteborg.se/ParkingService/v2.1/help" and I would like to do something similiar but with an IP-address.

Comment: URLs get resolved to IP addresses, so there should be no difference at all between the two. Do you get any errors?

Comment: @erikvdde Ok Sorry. Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I was unable to do an `HttpURLconnection` at all and I had to do it in another way.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting your ip address with the protocol identifier "http" E.g.

```
http://192.168.1.20/api/users
```